# JSON format for Stackdriver logging in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently looking for simplest possible JSON log messages that would simply write a severity and a message to Stackdriver logging from a container that is run in Kubernetes Engine and is using the managed Fluentd daemon.

Basically I'm writing single line JSON entries as follows.

```js
{"severity": "DEBUG", "message": "I'm a debug entry"}
{"severity": "ERROR", "message": "I'm an error entry"}
```

These end up in Stackdriver logging with following results.

- Severity is always INFO
- There's JSON payload in the log entry, and the only content is the message, i.e. severity does not go there.

My conclusion is that Fluentd recognizes log row as JSON, but what I don't understand is that how the severity is not set into log entries correctly. Am I e.g. missing some mandatory fields that need to be in place?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using a client library that would do the correct formatting automatically?

Comment: Trying to migrate tens of existing services to Kubernetes.

Comment: @JordiMiralles Said client libraries can be unreasonably large, when all you wanted was a single struct definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the information you provided I guess fluentd is passing your whole JSON as as a jsonpayload as a [logEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) and providing the logName, resource type and the rest of required information from the environment variables.

In the end what Stackdriver is receiving must look something like this:

```
{
 "logName": "projects/[YOUR PROJECT ID]/logs/[KUBERNETES LOG]",
 "entries": [
  {
   "jsonPayload": {
    "message": "I'm an ERROR entry",
    "severity": "ERROR"
   },
   "resource": {
    "labels": {
     "project_id": "[YOUR PROJECT ID]",
     "instance_id": "[WHATEVER]",
     "zone": "[YOUR ZONE]"
    },
    "type": "gce_instance"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

So you are actually getting the content of the JSON payload on Stackdriver, but as the severity is defined either **outside** the JSON payload or, if you want to do it inside you'll have to use `"severity": enum([NUMERICAL VALUE])`

[The numerical values of each log level are:](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity)

> Enums
>   DEFAULT (0) The log entry has no assigned severity level.
>   DEBUG   (100) Debug or trace information.
>   INFO    (200) Routine information, such as ongoing status or performance.
>   NOTICE  (300) Normal but significant events, such as start up, shut down, or a configuration change.
>   WARNING (400) Warning events might cause problems.
>   ERROR   (500) Error events are likely to cause problems.
>   CRITICAL    (600) Critical events cause more severe problems or outages.
>   ALERT   (700) A person must take an action immediately.
>   EMERGENCY   (800) One or more systems are unusable.

So, including the field `"severity": enum(500)` should log the entry as an ERROR instead to fallback to the default INFO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My conclusion of the logging behavior is the following.

Comment: I've answered separately, and unable to edit my previous reply anymore.

Comment: Looking again your answer, and it looks to match the format except that when working correctly the severity is not inside jsonPayload, i.e. Stackdriver identifies the field and moves it to top level on the LogEntry.

Answer (score 3):

My conclusion of the logging behavior is the following as I've now got things working.

- GKE handles the resource/logName part, no need to worry about this one.
- You can log any JSON structure, it will go into jsonPlayload
- Plain text log rows go into plainText, and same applies e.g. to broken JSON. In few occasions I've seen two JSON log rows in a single textPayload, i.e. broken JSON. Whether it's my applications or something else, I don't know yet.
- There are special JSON fields such as severity that will not go into jsonPayload. Works as documented in [GCP logging entry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry).

Answer (score 3):

an update for logging severity, severity can be logged within the `jsonPayload` and the fluentd daemon moves it to the outside of jsonPayload. it works with using the string values of severity and not the enums, eg, `"severity": "ERROR"` inside `jsonPayload` works fine.